# NoClassDeffoundError on PayPalConfiguration file

Tags: android, paypal

I am using new PayPal SDK for payment purpose in our application, I getting crash while opening of that activity in which PayPal code has written. Below is the code as:

```
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Hipster Store")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
```

Below is the Logcat for the same:

```
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): Process: com.parisimagination.okay, PID: 2621
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalConfiguration;
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.parisimagination.okay.myaccount.MyAccount.<clinit>(MyAccount.java:72)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.parisimagination.okay.mainscreen.MainActivity$8.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:603)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3845)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3617)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-30 14:56:50.354: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.parisimagination.okay-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.parisimagination.okay-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /syste
```

I unable to find the cause why its not running, please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which IDE your are using android studio or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse....

Answer (score 0):

There's a [known issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/90) with using Eclipse.